# What are the possible values for format in a font-face src?

Tags: css, fonts, format, font-face

And how to know what to use, when, and are they ever actually required?

Many Websites have examples like the following, with varying orders:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.eot'); 
  src: url('Example.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('Example.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Example.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Example.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('Example.svg#svgExample') format('svg');
}
```

But I've also seen examples like these:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.woff2') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.ttf') format('woff2-variations');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.otf'); 
}
```

Sometimes the format seems identical to the file ending, sometimes what the file ending abbreviates or partially atleast, while other times they seem to be completly random strings, or sometimes nothing if it's just one file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not important to know **all possible format values** - a lot of them go back to formerly experimental browser implementations.

Actually, you may compare some format values to CSS browser prefixes – fortunately, they've become less relevant – unfortunately, they can still be relevant now and then.

### TL;DR: prefer WOFF2 and WOFF

WOFF and WOFF2 are actually container formats wrapping .otf or .ttf  opentype font files (we get to it later) in a more efficiently compressed file – resulting in shorter loading times.

#### WOFF/WOFF2 Implementation history

To give you an idea about the history of browser support/implemenation
(I use the notoriously lagging-behind/standard-defying Microsoft browsers as a benchmark: ie or Edge):

- **woff(v1)**: [was specified ~2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format) and implemented by all major browsers (yes even by ie9!) in 2011 (others like Firefox even in 2010)
- **woff2**: documentation is a bit wobbly but we it's safe to say we got  a pretty complete major browser support somewhere [around 2016](https://caniuse.com/?search=woff2). Internet Explorer (11) was "already" discontinued at this time and replaced with edge. Apples Safari was also lagging behind due to OSX version shifts.

You should prefer woff2 in your `@font-face` src property stack by moving their url to the top:

**Not ideal: most browsers will first load woff(1) instead of woff2**

```CSS
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Example.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Example.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

**Better: prioritize woff2 by stacking order**

```CSS
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Example.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Example.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Be careful: Concatenate multiple font file urls with a comma as separator. Make sure you end the `src` property with a semicolon (OK you can omit it if it's the last property in your CSS rule. Just don't confuse comma with semicolon within the src stack)

Frankly, all modern browsers support woff2 so you can safely remove most of the older formats.

### Other formats

Referring to your first `@font-face` example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.eot'); 
  src: url('Example.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('Example.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Example.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Example.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('Example.svg#svgExample') format('svg');
}
```

#### .otf format('opentype')

The `.otf` is actually missing – but it's quite irrelevant for web usage.

```
src: url("Example.otf") format("opentype");
```

Similar to truetype they can be installed locally and used in any desktop application.

In type foundry lingo: OTF font files are also referred to as "post-script flavored" Open Type fonts (using [CFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff) or [CFF2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cff2) outline formats).
Whereas .ttf/truetype fonts are also called "Truetype flavored" Open Type fonts.

`.otf` font files are lacking advanced file compression compared to woff2.

#### .ttf format('truetype')

Probably the best supported font format (based on the [glyf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/glyf) format), but not as compact as woff2 or woff.
Besides, truetype fonts can be used in desktop environments so locally installed and used in any application.

Still relevant for some use cases like pdf conversions.

#### .eot format('embedded-opentype') – deprecated

Only used by Internet Explorers – but even these atrocities were capable of rendering at least ttf/truetype.

**`.eot` is obsolete**
(unless you need to maintain some embedded system running on a special window embedded system).

#### .svg format('svg') – deprecated

Only supported by webkit browsers (safari, epiphany, midori) and android browsers.
However, all these aforementioned browsers also support woff2, woff or truetype.
Most importantly, not supported by Chromium/Blink based browsers (opera, Vivaldi, Brave, Internet Explorer 13/Edge) or Firefox.

No need for `.svg` font files (although they can be handy as a **interchange format for icon generators** like icomoon or fontello)

#### Variable fonts

You might encounter legacy notations like in this post: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/newsletter/259-how-to-use-variable-fonts/)

```
  src: url("Example.woff2") format("woff2 supports variations"),
       url("Example.woff2") format("woff2-variations");
```

These extra format types originate from the days, when variable font support was rather experimental.
Nowadays, they are not needed – just use the normal format identifier.

#### You *may* also ditch the format as well

Most modern browsers, can map font files to font-families even without a specified format.
However it's still a good idea to include them.

##### But: wrong format values break your @font-face rule!

Common mistake:

```
url('Example.ttf') format('ttf') /* not correct */
```

instead of

```
url('Example.ttf') format('truetype') /* correct */
```

#### ... don't forget the weight and style properties

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Example.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Example.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight:400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: 100%;
}

/* next font style: e.g bold italic condensed */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Example';
  src: url('Example_boldItalicCn.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Example_boldItalicCn.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Example_boldItalicCn.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight:700;
  font-style: italic;
  font-stretch: 50%;
}
```

#### Variable font @font-face

In this case, font-weight and other properties contain 2 values to define a range like e.g `font-weight: 100 1000`.

```CSS
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Example;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100 1000;
    font-stretch: 0% 200%;
    src: url('Example.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```